# WiFi-module problems on Lenovo T440s with Fedora 19/20 (3.13+)

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, fedora

I've already searched the web but found no proper solution for my problem.
the drivers are afais the newest (directly from intel-pages).

I'm running Fedora 20 on a recently bought Lenovo Thinkpad T440s with an intel 7260 WLAN-device. Since the day of receipt and shortly after the installation of Fedora 19, I've got connection problems via wireless LAN (via Ethernet not at all).
After an upgrade to Fedora 20 the problem/s continued.

My only approach is this extract of my log (the errors are nearly always the same), which you can see here (it's fresh)

```
Mar 27 19:32:21 stealth dbus[956]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.problems'
Mar 27 19:32:22 stealth abrt-server: Duplicate: core backtrace
Mar 27 19:32:22 stealth abrt-server: DUP_OF_DIR: /var/tmp/abrt/oops-2014-03-21-11:15:57-2106-0
Mar 27 19:32:22 stealth abrt-server: Deleting problem directory oops-2014-03-27-19:32:20-1827-1 (dup of oops-2014-03-21-11:15:57-2106-0)
Mar 27 19:32:23 stealth abrt-dump-oops: Reported 2 kernel oopses to Abrt
Mar 27 19:32:27 stealth kernel: [  334.542883] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Failing on timeout while stopping DMA channel 0 [0x5a5a5a5a]
Mar 27 19:32:27 stealth kernel: [  336.380011] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Failing on timeout while stopping DMA channel 2 [0x5a5a5a5a]
Mar 27 19:32:27 stealth kernel: [  338.254690] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Failing on timeout while stopping DMA channel 5 [0x5a5a5a5a]
Mar 27 19:32:27 stealth kernel: [  340.095838] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Failing on timeout while stopping DMA channel 7 [0x5a5a5a5a]
Mar 27 19:32:27 stealth kernel: iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Failing on timeout while stopping DMA channel 0 [0x5a5a5a5a]
Mar 27 19:32:27 stealth kernel: iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Failing on timeout while stopping DMA channel 2 [0x5a5a5a5a]
Mar 27 19:32:27 stealth kernel: iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Failing on timeout while stopping DMA channel 5 [0x5a5a5a5a]
Mar 27 19:32:27 stealth kernel: iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Failing on timeout while stopping DMA channel 7 [0x5a5a5a5a]
Mar 27 19:32:29 stealth kernel: [  341.900469] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Disabled; Enabling L0S
Mar 27 19:32:29 stealth kernel: [  341.918142] [sched_delayed] sched: RT throttling activated
Mar 27 19:32:29 stealth kernel: iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Disabled; Enabling L0S
Mar 27 19:32:29 stealth kernel: [sched_delayed] sched: RT throttling activated
Mar 27 19:32:29 stealth kernel: [  342.041989] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Disabled; Enabling L0S
Mar 27 19:32:29 stealth kernel: iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Disabled; Enabling L0S
Mar 27 19:32:42 stealth kernel: [  347.860153] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Failed to load firmware chunk!
Mar 27 19:32:42 stealth kernel: [  347.860158] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Could not load the [0] uCode section
Mar 27 19:32:42 stealth kernel: [  347.860163] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Failed to start RT ucode: -110
Mar 27 19:32:42 stealth kernel: [  349.672452] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Failing on timeout while stopping DMA channel 0 [0x5a5a5a5a]
Mar 27 19:32:42 stealth kernel: [  351.511049] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Failing on timeout while stopping DMA channel 2 [0x5a5a5a5a]
Mar 27 19:32:42 stealth kernel: [  353.384834] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Failing on timeout while stopping DMA channel 5 [0x5a5a5a5a]
Mar 27 19:32:42 stealth kernel: [  355.223474] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Failing on timeout while stopping DMA channel 7 [0x5a5a5a5a]
Mar 27 19:32:42 stealth kernel: iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Failed to load firmware chunk!
Mar 27 19:32:42 stealth kernel: iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Could not load the [0] uCode section
Mar 27 19:32:42 stealth kernel: iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Failed to start RT ucode: -110
Mar 27 19:32:42 stealth kernel: iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Failing on timeout while stopping DMA channel 0 [0x5a5a5a5a]
Mar 27 19:32:42 stealth kernel: iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Failing on timeout while stopping DMA channel 2 [0x5a5a5a5a]
Mar 27 19:32:42 stealth kernel: iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Failing on timeout while stopping DMA channel 5 [0x5a5a5a5a]
Mar 27 19:32:42 stealth kernel: iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Failing on timeout while stopping DMA channel 7 [0x5a5a5a5a]
Mar 27 19:33:02 stealth dbus-daemon: dbus[956]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.ModemManager1' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.ModemManager1.service'
Mar 27 19:33:02 stealth dbus[956]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.ModemManager1' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.ModemManager1.service'
Mar 27 19:33:02 stealth dbus[956]: [system] Activation via systemd failed for unit 'dbus-org.freedesktop.ModemManager1.service': Unit dbus-org.freedesktop.ModemManager1.service failed to load: No such file or directory.
Mar 27 19:33:02 stealth dbus-daemon: dbus[956]: [system] Activation via systemd failed for unit 'dbus-org.freedesktop.ModemManager1.service': Unit dbus-org.freedesktop.ModemManager1.service failed to load: No such file or directory.
Mar 27 19:34:17 stealth kernel: [  450.493045] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: iwl_trans_send_cmd bad state = 0
Mar 27 19:34:17 stealth kernel: [  450.493050] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Scan failed! status 0x1 ret -5
Mar 27 19:34:17 stealth kernel: iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: iwl_trans_send_cmd bad state = 0
Mar 27 19:34:17 stealth kernel: iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Scan failed! status 0x1 ret -5
```

For more information, here is the relevant `lspci` output

```
03:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 7260 (rev 83)
```

and my `rfkill` list

```
0: tpacpi_bluetooth_sw: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
16: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Does anyone have any idea what is causing this problem and how to resolve it?

Comment: The usual suspect is always the hw driver. Quickest test is to boot fedora live and check whether the wifi is working or not.

Comment: well I think I already stated that out, because as I was installing Fedora 19, the wifi-device weren't detected at all. Meanwhile I'm more and more convinced that it is the driver or anything that interferes with it.

Comment: sorry, I didn't understood the "shortly after the installation" as "since booting the Fedora 19". I've found this http://blog.ometer.com/2013/12/04/fedora-20-beta-on-thinkpad-t440s-report/and the guy said it works nice, but YMMV. However, take a look at this thread http://www.experts-exchange.com/OS/Linux/Distributions/Q_28360458.html where the guy have same problem as you and also there is some kind of solution there.